# How get button value from php loop using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make operations(delete and edit) using javascript for each element of list. I took list from mysql database. The javascript function is returning just last value of list.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blSfK.png)

This is php back-end

```
do{
     echo " <li class='list-group-item note'><div><strong>".$fetch['title']."</strong>
     <small>".$fetch['notedate']."</small></div>
     <div>
     <button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-primary' id='edit' value=".$fetch['id'].">&#9998;</button>
     <button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-danger' onClick='deleteData()' id='delete' value='".$fetch['id']."'>&times;</button>
     </div>
     </li>";
    }
    while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli_query));
```

javascript:

```
function deleteData (){
var acc = document.getElementById("delete");
alert (acc);  
}
```

I want javascript function return value of button individually. For exampe:  if I click the buton with value=2 javascript should return 2, if 3 then 3.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to deliberately use a `do-while()` loop to iterate your result set, it is probably a bad idea because it fetches the row AFTER each iteration (assuming a row exists).

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Also you'll want to set unique values for "id"

```
do{
         echo " <li class='list-group-item note'><div><strong>".$fetch['title']."</strong>
         <small>".$fetch['notedate']."</small></div>
         <div>
         <button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-primary' id='edit' value=".$fetch['id'].">&#9998;</button>
         <button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-danger' onClick='deleteData(this.value)' id='delete' value='".$fetch['id']."'>&times;</button>
         </div>
         </li>";
        }
        while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli_query));
```

then

```
    function deleteData (acc){
      alert (acc);  
   }
```